# What would be the regex to use to find a potential space at the very end of files with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have hundreds of files to look in to check if there is not an extra line with a space which cause my PHP application to throw hundreds of Warning in the logs.

I cannot find the regex to match a space (or tab) at the end of a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Please note, this seems to only work in Notepad++ 6.0 (or above).
>
>   Version 6.0 included [support for PCRE](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html), which is required for this to work.**

Search for `\z` (That's a space, followed by a backslash, followed by the letter `z`). That should do :)

`\z` marks the [end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regex-to-match-eof).

[image]

If you want to find any whitespace at the end of the file, use `\s+\z`. `\s` means *any whitespace character*:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work with my Notepad++ on Windows 7, have you tried it yourself ?

Comment: @Gueno: Yes. Worked like a charm (also on Windows 7). I even tested with possible false positives. Maybe it's not actually a space.

Comment: I may have the wrong parameters somewhere... Regex mode or extended mode ? I do have a space when testing in a dummy file, I even tested with the letter 'k' instead of a space as last line, but `k\z` doesn't match it :(

Comment: @Gueno: Maybe it's a version issue. I have Notepad++ 6.1.2 (just updated) but it also worked with 6.0 (before I updated). The mode is "Regular expression" (as in the screenshot).

Comment: maybe, I use 5.9.1, will try to update it and come back to give feedback

Comment: @Gueno: I'm pretty sure this *feature* came with the 6.0 update (because that's when they added PCRE support). I updates my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Works fine with the 6.1.2 I just installed, thank you @Oliver Salzburg